# log file not getting generated

Tags: java, log4j

i have a batch file from which i am invoking some of the stuff and also the log

```
set LOG4J="-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=%DIR%\log4j.properties"
java %LOG4J% -Dwvs.some.properties=%DIR%\xyz.properties  %DEBUG% -PORT %PORT% -HOST %HOST% -TYPE %TYPE% -CMDCLASS %CMDCLASS% >stdout.log 2>&1
```

the port, host, cmdclass,DIR, type have proper values and this is my log4j.properties file, i am on windows machine.

```
# Set root logger to output only ERROR and FATAL events to R appender
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,R

# Define R appender to output to local log
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=D:/logs/sample.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

on D:\logs , nothing gets generated, i am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by changing this :

`set LOG4J="-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=%DIR%\log4j.properties"` to

`set LOG4J="-Dlog4j.configuration=%DIR%\log4j.properties"`

Answer (score 0):

log4j properties are case sensitive

log4j.appender.R.File
should be log4j.appender.R.file

Comment: Also -Dlog4j.configuration=%DIR%\log4j.properties should be -Dlog4j.configuration=file:%DIR%\log4j.properties